# Inherit and modify a `Meta` class

Tags: python, django, django-tables2

So I have a base ItemTable, and then a number of Tables that inherit from it.  I don't seem to be able to modify the Meta class.  I tried just including the meta class normally and it didn't work, then I found [this bug report](https://github.com/bradleyayers/django-tables2/issues/85) and implemented it below.  It fails silently:  the tables render only with the columns from the parent meta class.

```
class ItemTable(tables.Table):

    class Meta:
        model = Item
        attrs = {"class":"paleblue"}
        fields = ('name', 'primary_tech', 'primary_biz', 'backup_tech', 'backup_biz')

class ApplicationTable(ItemTable):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ApplicationTable, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    class Meta(ItemTable.Meta):
        model = Application
        fields += ('jira_bucket_name',)
```

EDIT:  Code amended as shown.  I now get a NameError that `fields` is not defined.

Comment: A class named `Meta` and `Metaclass` are two different things.

Comment: ok... well, terminology aside--and I'll be sure to research that--what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```
class ApplicationTable(ItemTable):
    class Meta:
        model = Application
        fields = ItemTable.Meta.fields + ('jira_bucket_name',)
```

You'll have the same problems extending `Meta` in a table, as you will in a normal Django model.

Comment: This fails silently, but does not add the new columns. FWIW, this is the first time I've ever tried extending `Meta`, so I don't know how it compares to a non-django-tables2 model.

Comment: There was an embarrassing level of idiocy on my part that kept this from working.  This is the correct solution.  Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You didnt add `,` (comma) to one-element tuple. Try to change this line `Meta.attrs['fields'] += ('jira_bucket_name')` in `ApplicationTable` to:

```
Meta.attrs['fields'] += ('jira_bucket_name',)
```

if it didnt help try to create Meta class outsite model class definition:

```
class ItemTableMeta:
    model = Item
    attrs = {"class":"paleblue"}
    fields = ('name', 'primary_tech', 'primary_biz', 'backup_tech', 'backup_biz')

class ApplicationTableMeta(ItemTableMeta):
    model = Application
    fields = ItemTableMeta.fields + ('jira_bucket_name',)


class ItemTable(tables.Table):
    #...
    Meta = ItemTableMeta

class ApplicationTable(ItemTable):
    #...
    Meta = ApplicationTableMeta
```

Comment: Good catch, but didn't help with this problem.

Comment: No dice:  All the tables still are only recognizing the parent ItemTableMeta.  No error messages.

Comment: @thumbtackthief it is a django-tables issue, found this in docs https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#meta-inheritance

Answer (score 0):

You may need to take this up with the django-tables author. This is not a problem with standard Django.

Comment: I've added to the known bug report (2 years old) but haven't gotten a response yet.